# How to format negative numbers in django-tables2?

Tags: python, django, django-tables2

I am looking for nice solution to make a simple subclassed NumericColumn for my tables, based on django-tables2. I started with that:

```
class NumericColumn(Column):

    def render(self, value):
        return '{:0,.2f}'.format(value)
```

It works great until I decided to make negative values red:

```
class NumericColumn(Column):
    attrs = {
        'td': {
            'class': lambda value: 'text-danger' if value < 0 else ''
        }
    }
    
    def render(self, value):
        return '{:0,.2f}'.format(value)
```

Code periodically fails with `TypeError: '<' not supported between instances of 'str' and 'int'`, and it seems that lambda function receives already formatted `value`. I don't see a way to get an original value in `record` via accessor, and I don't think that it is nice to make a reverse conversion to Decimal for such comparison. Ok, I can test first character for '-', but it is too ugly.

Please help.

Comment: Your method's definition looks fine, but how is it used? It looks like the problem comes from another part of your code. Are you sure `value` is actually always an `int`? What's this `record`?

Comment: I think that the problem is that `value` seems to come to lambda function already formatted by `render` method, and if I try to convert `value` to `int` or `Decimal`, I receive an error like this: `could not convert string to float: '1,750.40'`

Answer (score 0):

The type of `value` seems `string` while you are trying to compare it with an `integer`, so to fix this issue you can just make sure it's converted to `float` because you are using float value not string.

Change it like this:

```
lambda value: 'text-danger' if float(value) < 0 else ''
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I thought of course that type of `value` should be specified explicit (I used `Decimal` but there is no difference); however the problem is that `value` seems to come to lambda function already formatted by `render` method, and I receive an error like this: `could not convert string to float: '1,750.40'`

Answer (score 0):

You may be able to use a solution like the one included in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/17815252), which uses locale to parse numbers in strings.

For your use, you could try it like this:

(first make sure to import locale and set the appropriate locale. I'm guessing you are using something like US, based on the comma separation of your example number)

```python
import locale
locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'en_US.UTF-8')
```

Then:

```python
lambda value: 'text-danger' if locale.atof(value) < 0 else ''
```